# How does Rails handle conflicting dependent: :destroy and dependent: :restrict_with_error in child records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Suppose I have these three models:

```
class Owner < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :businesses, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :stores, through: :businesses, dependent: :destroy
end

class Business < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner
  has_many :stores, dependent: :restrict_with_error
end

class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :business
end
```

I would like to for all associated records of the owner to be destroyed once the owner records is destroyed. Would destroying an owner record in this case guarantee destroying the associated store and business records? If not, would the correct approach be to destroy all store records first and then destroy the owner?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so it turns out that the :restrict_with_error prevents the destruction of business records even with the dependent: :destroy on the owner class.